# Laravel Vite Asset Implementation

Tags: laravel, vite

I do have an js asset installed via npm in node_modules folder.
How can I include that asset file in specific frontend views without compiling it into the main js file or copy it into the public/ folder?

I used the @vite(['node_modules/...']) directive to include it in my file. This worked, but I don't think that pointing to node_modules/ folder from the frontend is a common practice.

Comment: You are right, it is not common practice to directly point to node_modules. Compiling it in the main js file IS common practice. I don't think it's that important though because when you build the assets vite is probably going to copy that file in your public folder anyway

Comment: But it is an asset, which is not needed on every site. So, what would be common to do in that case?

Comment: Personally I have one common entry point that is included in all files and if specific files need additional things I make another entry point and only put the @vite annotation in the specific blade I need it in.

Comment: Thank you for that hint. Could you give me an example how I can implement that in the vite.config.js?

Comment: If [this](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/10.x/vite.config.js) is your starting point you can add another string after `'resources/js/app.js'` that will be your additional starting point (e.g. `'resources/js/page.js'`). This will get built but will only be loaded in places where you use `@vite([ 'resources/js/page.js' ])`